# Find the upper central series of $D_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $D_6 = \{1, r, r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, s, sr, sr^2, sr^3, sr^4, sr^5\} $ and $\mathbb{Z}_5 = \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$.
The center of $G$ is $\operatorname{Z}(G) = \{g \in G \;|\; \forall h\in G,\, gh=hg\}$.

> Find the upper central series of $D_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: The question is unclear : do you want the central series of the center ?

Comment: Sorry, upper central series*

Comment: Do you have any thoughts? To start with, what is the center of $D_6 \times \mathbb Z_5$?

Comment: Well I know the center for d6 is {1, r^3} and for z5 is z5.

Comment: OK, and for a direct product $A \times B$, what is the relationship between $Z(A \times B)$ and the centers of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: It is the ordered pair of the values I just stated, no?

Comment: Well, to say it more correctly, it is the direct product of $Z(A)$ and $Z(B)$. So in your case, $Z(G) = Z(D_6 \times \mathbb Z_5) = Z(D_6) \times Z(\mathbb Z_5) = \{1, r^3\} \times \mathbb Z_5$. So in particular, $Z(G)$ has order $10$, therefore $G / Z(G)$ has order $6$. Up to isomorphism, there are only two groups of order $6$, one is $\mathbb Z_6$ and the other is $S_3$. Which of these is $G / Z(G)$?

Comment: Could it also be D3? To answer your question, I am not sure

Comment: Note that $D_3 \cong S_3$. To avoid too many comments, I will go ahead and write up an answer. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 2):

We will use the following notation for the upper central series of a group $G$:

$$1 = Z_0 \lhd Z_1 \lhd Z_2 \lhd \cdots$$
where $Z_1 = Z(G)$, and for $n > 1$, $Z_n/Z_{n-1} = Z(G/Z_{n-1})$.

For a finite group, there are two possibilities:

- $Z_n = G$ for some $n$, which happens iff $G$ is nilpotent, or
- For some $n$, we have $Z_{n-1} = Z_n < G$, so the series terminates before reaching $G$

Recall (or prove) the following easy facts about direct products.

**Fact 1:**

$Z(A \times B) = Z(A) \times Z(B)$

**Fact 2:**

If $H \lhd A$ and $K \lhd B$, then $H \times K \lhd A \times B$, and
$$(A \times B)/(H \times K) \cong (A / H) \times (B / K)$$

---

In your case, $A = D_6$ and $B = \mathbb Z_5$. As you noted in the comments, $Z(A) = \{1,r^3\}$ and $Z(\mathbb Z_5) = \mathbb Z_5$.

Using **Fact 1**, this means that
$$Z_1 = Z(G) = Z(D_6 \times \mathbb Z_5) = Z(D_6) \times Z(\mathbb Z_5) = \{1,r^3\} \times \mathbb Z_5$$

Since $|Z(G)| = 10$, this means that $|G/Z(G)| = 6$. Moreover, using **Fact 2** we have
$$G/Z(G) = (D_6 \times \mathbb Z_5) / (\{1,r^3\} \times \mathbb Z_5) \cong (D_6 / \{1,r^3\}) \times 1 \cong D_6 / \{1,r^3\}$$
Now, $D_6 / \{1, r^3\}$ has order $6$. Up to isomorphism, there are only two groups of order $6$, namely $\mathbb Z_6$ and $S_3$.

If $D_6 / \{1, r^3\} \cong \mathbb Z_6$, then there must be some coset $g\{1, r^3\}$ with order $6$, so $g$ must have order $6$ in $D_6$. Therefore $g = r$ or $g = r^{-1}$. But for these elements, $g\{1, r^3\}$ has order $3$. Therefore $D_6 / \{1, r^3\}$ cannot be $\mathbb Z_6$.

Consequently, $D_6 / \{1, r^3\} \cong S_3$. But $S_3$ has trivial center, so $Z_2 / Z_1 = 1$, so $Z_2 = Z_1$ and we have reached the end of the upper central series already.